# JavaScript: Array vs Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am running into a problem where a function I am running works fine with one array and not all all with another.

They are being created in different ways and are obviously different based on what I see in the Console, but I can not figure out the difference. Can someone point me in the right direction? Sorry if this is JavaScript 101.  A screenshot of each array's definition is below, and then a snapshot from my Console.

```
var working = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]

var notWorking= [];
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                var latlng ={lat: parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                            lng: parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng'))};
            notWorking.push(latlng);
```

[ScreenshotOfConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc07m.jpg)

Comment: Those arrays seem the same to me. Both array of objects. Each object with lat and lng property.

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) showing the issue?

Comment: I think you need to flatten your array!

Comment: It's probably has something to do with the asynchrounosity of the second method (You are using the array while it is not filled by the asynchronous function)!

Comment: Can you post the code that surrounds the second method and where you are using the not working array?

Answer (score 1):

Check that `data.responseXML` is formatted the way it should

Here is a sample code that works, it's the same code as yours except XML document is loaded from a String :

```js
var working = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]

var notWorking= [];
var xmlString = '<markers><marker lat="-31.563910" lng="147.154312"></marker><marker lat="-31.563910" lng="147.154312"></marker></markers>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"); //important to use "text/xml"
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
     var latlng ={lat: parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  lng: parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng'))};
 notWorking.push(latlng);
});

console.log(notWorking)
```

If you don't find what's wrong with your xml, please edit your answer and paste `data.responseXml` this way :

```
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(data.responseXML);
console.log(sXML)
```

Comment: I've added a sample code on how to serialize your xml document

Answer (score 0):

When the console log was called on the `notWorking` array it was empty! So this is probably an issue of using an array before it's filled by an asynchronous function. When you unfold the logged array, there is a note that states that the value of the array has been just evaluated:

[image]

That means that when unfolding the array's log, the console get the value of the array at that moment (which is probably after the array has been filled with values). The empty log (`[]`) before the unfolding justifies the assumption that when the log happened, the array was empty.

Looking at your code, it looks like an XMLHttpRequest (asynchronous). If you want to use the value of the array, you'll have to use it in the callback of the request ot in the callback of the success event listener of the request where it's is assured that the array is filled!

Answer (score 0):

If you working array is:

```
var working = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}];
```

then you need to flatten your array to make look like your working array:

```
var arr = [{lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}];
var arrayOfObj = [];
arrayOfObj.push(arr);

console.log(arr);

var flattenArr  =  arrayOfObj.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(flattenArr));
```

```js
var arr = [{lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}];
var arrayOfObj = [];
arrayOfObj.push(arr);

console.log(arrayOfObj);

var flattenArr  =  arrayOfObj.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(flattenArr));
```

Comment: Where do you all get this idea that the array is not flattened?

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted isn't valid. The function is not closed. I think you forgot to copy the part where you logged the variables.

I'm going to make a guess that you're confused about the what you're seeing in the console, because it shows you an empty array, but then there's data inside of it. What's going on is that the array is still empty when it's logged, then it gets populated, and then you open it and see the data. The console doesn't update it's content when the values change, only when it renders.